# Rotation multiplying by $i$ in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

In comparison to $\arg(z)$, what would $\arg(zi)$ look like?

My answer: Rotation by $-\pi/2$, which adds $\pi/2$ to the argument.

Friend: Rotation by $\pi/2$, which minuses $\pi/2$ to the argument.

:( This might be stupid so sorry in advance haha

Comment: Both of you are wrong. A rotation of $+\pi/2$ in the complex plane **adds** $\pi/2$ to the argument. Both angles are measured counterclockwise. Note, however, that the [principal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value) may wrap around.

Comment: Hey jean, thanks for your answer. So would u say the line is rotated pi/2 anticlockwise, which adds pi/2 to the argument? So to clarify, the line would be in the second quadrant?

Comment: Depends on where it is before the rotation. There is no line in the question. Besides, a line, infinite in both directions, does never lie in a single quadrant.

Comment: thank u so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $i=\exp\frac{\pi i}{2}$, $\operatorname{arg}(zi)\equiv\operatorname{arg}(z)+\frac{\pi}{2}(\bmod 2\pi)$. A restriction of arguments to an interval of length $2\pi$ obtains $\operatorname{arg}(zi)-\operatorname{arg}(z)\in\{-\frac{3\pi}{2},\,\frac{\pi}{2}\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)